# Lotus notes- shared, private on first use folder and LotusScript

Tags: lotusscript, lotus

I am doing lotus notes customized search using form to give them to choose different criteria to choose upon.

when they hit the search button I am building search string and doing db.search, now I have done code like it would put all the collection of notes document to shared, private on first use folder and below is the code.

Call doccoll.putallinfolder("SearchResult")

But this gives me error that can not be accessed, please note that default is sent to Manager in the databse and has access to create private and SPOU view as well.

Please help me what has been gone wrong here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The private instance of a SPOFU folder does not exist until the user opens it with the client for the first time. Before that point, only the shared instance exists, but that only contains the design; you can't put documents into the shared instance. The `putAllInFolder` method will not create the shared instance for you, but I believe that the `NotesDatabase.EnableFolder` method will, so try calling that first.

Comment: My other query is that, on SPOFU folders I put the search result, but it does keep adding search result to previous search result I mean documents from searchresults, it should always contain latest search result, is there any way   that I can clear them off before putting new search documents to it. I tried to delete documents from SPOFU but it deletes from the database.

Comment: You need to loop through the documents in the folder and call the NotesDoducment.RemoveFromFolder("SearchResult") method. And I strongly recommend that before you continue programming this project, you should review the documentation pages for all the Notes classes that you are using. You would have easily found this method if you had done that.

Comment: Thanks Richard, I was able to solve my issue with your kind help, thanks.

Comment: @hdc: as you never accepted an answer on StackOverflow yet, please, have a look here: https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235